# Findbugs error - RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED when using ImmutableSet.Builder

Tags: guava, findbugs, immutables-library

Findbugs throws warning for the following piece of code. Seems like a simple of `Builder` class to add items and construct at the end. Whats the issue here ?

```
public static Set<Entity> convert(@NonNull final String id,
        @NonNull final Collection<SomeEntity> list) {

        Builder<Entity> builder = new ImmutableSet.Builder<>();
        final Entity entityOfType1 = createEntity(..);        
  //    Bug type RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED 
        builder.add(entityOfType1);


        final Set<Entity> entitiesOfType2 = createEntity(..);
 //     Bug type RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED 
        builder.addAll(entitiesOfType2);

        final Set<Entity> entitiesOfType3 = createEntity(..);
 //     Bug type RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED 
        builder.addAll(entitiesOfType3);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, it's FindBugs issue.

If you switch to [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs), which is *"is the spiritual successor of FindBugs, carrying on from the point where it left off with support of its community"*, you'll have it fixed. [Guava since 23.6](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v23.6) *"migrated from jsr305 `@CheckReturnValue`, `@GuardedBy` and `@OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper` to the [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/) equivalents"*, for which support in SpotBugs was added in 2018 in [PR#538](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/pull/538).